# How can I add native features to Sensha without using a container?

Tags: barcode-scanner, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to Sensha.  The app I am developing uses a code scanner capability in smart phones.  I can add this functionality with PhoneGap / Cordova but my boss does't want to have to worry about app store submissions and wants to avoid client containers. Is there any other way to add scanner support to Sensha without the container?  ie. with just using a web-based app?